# Cannot call the second javascript function (differently named) on the same page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement an extend form function in two places on the same page. The first place works fine, but the second place does not even call the function apparently.

The html and js of the first place:

```
<span id="readroot" style="display: none">
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />
<div class="row">
    <!-- Content not displayed for simplicity purpose -->
</div>
</span>
<span id="writeroot"></span>        
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!" />
<script>
    var counter = 1;
    function moreFields() {
        counter++;
        var newField = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
        newField.id = '';
        newField.style.display = 'block';
        var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name], [id], [for]');
            for (var i=0;i<newFields.length;i++) {
                var theNames = newFields[i].name
                if (theNames)
                    newFields[i].name = "data[Student][" + counter + "][" + theNames + "]";
                var theNames2 = newFields[i].id;
                if (theNames2)
                    newFields[i].id = theNames2 + counter;
                var theNames3 = newFields[i].htmlFor;
                if (theNames3)
                    newFields[i].htmlFor = theNames3 + counter;
                    //console.log(newFields[i].htmlFor);    
            }           
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField,insertHere);
}
</script>
```

The second:

```
<span id="readroot2" style="display: none">
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />
<div class="row">
    <!-- Content not displayed for simplicity purpose -->
</div>  
</span>
<span id="writeroot2"></span>       
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onChange="moreFields2()" value="Give me more fields!" />
<script>
    var counter = 1;
    function moreFields2() {
        counter++;
        var newField = document.getElementById('readroot2').cloneNode(true);
        newField.id = '';
        newField.style.display = 'block';
        var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name], [id], [for]');
            for (var i=0;i<newFields.length;i++) {
                var theNames = newFields[i].name
                if (theNames)
                    newFields[i].name = "data[Condition][" + counter + "][" + theNames + "]";
                var theNames2 = newFields[i].id;
                if (theNames2)
                    newFields[i].id = theNames2 + counter;
                var theNames3 = newFields[i].htmlFor;
                if (theNames3)
                    newFields[i].htmlFor = theNames3 + counter;
            }           
        var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot2');
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField,insertHere);
    }
</script>
```

I have tried by naming all the variables in the second function differently. But it seems irrelevant..

Comment: What do you mean 'it doesn't work'? Please explain the expected outcome, and what specifically you need help with

Comment: It doesn't clone a form when a user clicks the 'Give me more fields' button.

Comment: the code doesn't look bad at all, have you tried debugging and check how far it runs?

Comment: I checked the newField variable in the second function with console log. It returned nothing..

Comment: Can you include more code so it can run? It looks like whatever you edited out may be important. Can you make a jsfiddle if you're worried about posting too much code here?

Comment: in second function you are calling function in `onChange` instead of `onClick`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have use two different events on both input

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields()"

<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onChange="moreFields2()"
```

So make sure that you are looking for same functionality on both than they will not..

onChange will fire after element change not while you type  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange2) check for code so be clear what you wanted.  Because onChange will fire on blur in this case

Answer (score 1):

The second function is not firing on **onChange** event. If you try to design the function accordingly you could have to reduce the effort to writing too many java script.

Comment: I am hoping not to duplicate the almost identical script. Could you advise?

Answer (score 1):

```
<span id="readroot" style="display: none">
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />
<div class="row">
    <!-- Content not displayed for simplicity purpose -->
</div>
</span>
    <span id="writeroot"></span>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="moreFields('readroot','writeroot')" value="Give me more fields!" />

    <span id="readroot2" style="display: none">
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />
<div class="row">
    <!-- Content not displayed for simplicity purpose -->
</div>  
</span>
    <span id="writeroot2"></span>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onClick="moreFields('readroot2','writeroot2')" value="Give me more fields!" />


<script>
    var counter = 1;

    function moreFields(node, insertNode) {

        counter++;
        var newField = document.getElementById(node).cloneNode(true);
        newField.id = '';
        newField.style.display = 'block';
        var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name], [id], [for]');
        for (var i = 0; i < newFields.length; i++) {
            var theNames = newFields[i].name
            if (theNames)
                newFields[i].name = "data[Condition][" + counter + "][" + theNames + "]";
            var theNames2 = newFields[i].id;
            if (theNames2)
                newFields[i].id = theNames2 + counter;
            var theNames3 = newFields[i].htmlFor;
            if (theNames3)
                newFields[i].htmlFor = theNames3 + counter;
        }
        var insertHere = document.getElementById(insertNode);
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField, insertHere);


    }
</script>
```

Please counter check it again for the functionality. And you may please optimize the code.